# Switching activities gives me a null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

Code to switch activities:

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,timeZones.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

once this part of the code has been hit, I get a null pointer exception here (specifically the 2nd line):

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

I tried adding a boolean to stop the canvas from drawing anything:

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,timeZones.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
dontDraw = true;


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (dontDraw == false)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Using this boolean, the activity timeZones runs, but it is just frozen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I am not fully get, why you not try to understand the base of your bug and instead of checking why `canvas` comes `null` you plant silly workarounds...

Comment: Please add more code. Does the code reaches the `onCreate` of the second activity?